# Rows.Remove() using simple operator

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

This code returns an generic error - is it not possible to use simple operators to remove rows from a data extension?

```
<script type="text/javaScript" runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    var DE_Lead_ExternalKey = "0CFBB346-2E4D-41CF-8649-CFF16A3CB6B2";
    var DE_Lead = DataExtension.Init(DE_Lead_ExternalKey);

    var filter = {Property:"EID",SimpleOperator:"contains",Value:"_temp"};
    var remove_rows = DE_Lead.Rows.Remove(filter);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. [Rows.Remove](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRemove.htm) will only accept an exact value match pair. E.g. `"name", "value"`.

It does not allow for any other simple operators or filters.

Ordinal   Type                      Description 

1      string  Required Fields used to filter row

2.     string  Required Values in fields used to filter row

Comment: Thank you. I will create a new boolean column and evaluate the value using a query activity, then perform an exact match. When evaluating a boolean field, do I need to include quotes for ordinal 2? e.g. DE_key.Rows.Retrieve(['field_name'],['true'])

Comment: No you should be fine with just `true`

Comment: I used the DeleteData platform function instead for deleting multiple rows. After some testing, it appears the quotes are required on boolean field values. E.G. DeleteData('DE_Name', ['field_name'], ['True']);